# How to handle the user logout in browser multiple tab?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, session

I am using codeigniter session to store user login. When user opens in multiple tab, on logout in one tab , I want the page to be auto refreshed while user visiting the other tab. Is this possible?

Comment: You would need to use Javascript to continuously monitor a cookie or a local storage object for changes and act accordingly.

Comment: Can you please explain with an example. I dont have idea about local storage (javascript)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just tested it out, and the easiest way I can see (which seems to work in Chrome at least, but may need further testing) is setting a cookie.

On logout do something like `setcookie('loggedout',1)`. You'll also need to do the opposite on login - `unset($_COOKIE['loggedout'])`

Then you just need some simple Javascript...

```
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = escape(name) + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) return unescape(c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length));
    }
    return null;
}
window.setInterval(function() {
    if(readCookie('loggedout')==1) {
        window.location.assign('loggedout.html')
        //Or whatever else you want!
    }
},1000)
```

That'll check each second to see if the cookie is set. Magic.

Comment: Will it notify other tabs of the logout/login event?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my below code to solve the issue. I set the cookie While login and deleted at logout. viceversa at Logout and Login also.

### Script:

```
function readCookie(name) {
var nameEQ = escape(name) + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) return unescape(c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length));
}
return null;
}

function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays)
{
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
} 

window.setInterval(function() {
if(readCookie('loggedout')==1) {

    window.location.reload();

   setCookie('loggedout',2,3);
    //Or whatever else you want!
}
 else if(readCookie('loggedin')==1) {

    window.location.reload();

   setCookie('loggedin',2,3);
    //Or whatever else you want!
}
},2000)
```

Controller:

### Login:

```
$this->load->helper('cookie');
    $cookie = array(
'name'   => 'loggedin',
'value'  => '1',
'expire' => '86500'
);
set_cookie($cookie);
$domain= preg_replace("/^[\w]{2,6}:\/\/([\w\d\.\-]+).*$/","$1", $this->config->slash_item('base_url')); 
$path = explode($domain,base_url());
delete_cookie('loggedout');
    delete_cookie('loggedout',$domain, $path[1] );
```

### Logout:

```
$cookie = array(
'name'   => 'loggedout',
'value'  => '1',
'expire' => '86500'
);
set_cookie($cookie);
$domain= preg_replace("/^[\w]{2,6}:\/\/([\w\d\.\-]+).*$/","$1", $this->config- >slash_item('base_url'));
$path = explode($domain,base_url());
delete_cookie('loggedin');

delete_cookie('loggedin','localhost', '/<!-- Your path -->/'); 

delete_cookie('loggedin',$domain, $path[1] );
```