# Multiple tab user logout works on two tabs only

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, session, cookies

Navigate here [How to handle the user logout in browser multiple tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692644/how-to-handle-the-user-logout-in-browser-multiple-tab/21718417#21718417)
I implement Automatic user login and logout using cookies, but one problem it works only on two tabs. when opened in more than two tabs, automatic login works in two tabs, other tabs remain unaffected.
Suggest me the cause or reason for the scenario.

Comment: Can you show us an example?

Answer (score 0):

Every call made to your application that request login should check if the user is logged.

If the user is not log, redirect him to the login page (or wherever you wish). If the call is made with ajax, you could return a 401 code and check with javascript if the return code is 401, then redirect the user in javascript.